# Fragment communication: which is the better approach?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I was working on communication between multiple fragments in a activity stack.
I have figured out 2 ways to do this.

1. Through interfaces
2. Through Bundle setarguments

   ```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putBoolean("Status",trur);
   Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(bottomfragment.class.getName());
   if(fragment!=null) {
       fragment.setArguments(bundle);
   }
   ```

I felt the 2nd approach easy.Since Google recommends 1 st approach
Can anyone help me with the problems I may face by following 2nd approach.

Comment: you can use `EVENTBUS`.https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus & http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html

Comment: Probably outside scope of changes you were hoping to make but what I find works well is shared `ViewModel` (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the both the ways.
1. through interfaces is if you want to communicate from fragment to activity or fragment to fragment(via activity)
2. set argument is if you want to pass arguments while starting the fragment. you can call methods of fragment using the instance you get from fragment id/tag
Please refer[fragment communication](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Answer (score 0):

Try to communication between two fragments like this:

1) Create Interface like this:

```
public interface FragmentChangeListener {
    void changeFragment(Fragment fragment);
}
```

2) Update MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentChangeListener
{
//Activity code
------
 @Override
    public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();
    tr.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    tr.commitAllowingStateLoss();
 }

}
```

3) Create First Fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment
{
 // call another freagment like this
//in your oncreateview method:
 SecondFragment
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable(SELECTED_ITEM, true);
            SecondFragment second =  SecondFragment.newInstance(b);

 FragmentChangeListener fc = (FragmentChangeListener) getActivity();
 fc.changeFragment(second);
}
```

4) Second Fragment:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static SecondFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        if (bundle != null)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
    }
//another fragment related code
//In your OncreateView like this:
if (getArguments() != null)
            boolean temp = getArguments().getBoolean(IntentParameter.SELECTED_ITEM);
    }
```

Hope this explanation help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Argument (`Bundle`) should be passed to `Fragment` only initially (when `Fragment`'s object is created by **default constructor**). Calling `setArguments` method on already added `Fragment` will cause `IllegalStateException`. See body of `setArguments` method:

```
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
       if (mIndex >= 0 && isStateSaved()) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active and state has been saved");
       }
            mArguments = args;
}
```

If you want to change something in `Fragment` **A** from `Fragment` **B** :

a) Get an object of **A** inside **B** using

`getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_A_TAG");`

Or

`getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(FRAGMENT_A_CONTAINER_ID);`

Cast returned object to **A** and call proper method on it. (It's the simplest way, but after it, **A** and **B** become highly coupled);

b) Alternatively, you can write mentioned logic inside method of `Activity`, which contains these 2 `Fragment`s, get reference of this `Activity` inside **B** using `getContext()` casted to container `Activity` and call mentioned method on it (It kills reusability, because if you want to have **A** and **B** on other `Activity`, casting `getContext()` will cause `ClassCastException`);

c) The best way, to communicate between `Fragment`s is to create `interface`, implement container `Activity` by this `interface`, get reference of this `interface` inside **B** and call proper method on it. (You can implement as many activities as you want by this interface, so it's reusable approach and **A** and **B** are loosely coupled).